# Describing data of different classes in JSON

Tags: json, jsonschema

What are ways to encode a value in JSON which is one of a set of predefined classes, along with class-specific attributes? I also have a requirement that the format can be fully validated with a json-schema (including non-presence of unneeded attributes).

An example would be: it is either a sphere with a specific radius, or a cube with specific dimensions.

A possible encoding for this example is:

```
{"class": "sphere", "sphereRadius": 1.6}
{"class": "cube", "cubeSizeX": 1, "cubeSizeY": 2, "cubeSizeZ": 3}
```

But I don't know if it's possible to define a json-schema describing the above format. I would need to specify that `sphereRadius` must be present if and only if `class` is equal to "sphere".

I am planning to use this in combination json-editor[1], which will build a user interface based on the schema. The result should be something like a drop-down menu where you select the class, and a set of fields where you enter the class-specific information.

[1] https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor

Comment: I actually attempted something similar a while back ([demo page](http://jsonary.com/documentation/json-schema/?section=keywords/General%20keywords#keywords/General%20keywords/05%20-%20oneOf)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `oneOf`, where each option has e.g.:

```
"properties": {
    "class": {"enum": ["sphere"]}
}
```

along with any sphere-specific constraints.  The drop-down interface you describe sounds like it would be a good representation for `"oneOf"` clauses, so that fits.

Comment: That indeed works, thanks. I also added "class" to "required".